# How to create a 4 corner, rounded divider in CSS

Tags: css

I have an element that I am using 'border-right: 2px solid black' to create dividers between columns.

The design team insists that the 'right border' must be rounded on all 4 corners like their mock up where they created a rounded rectangle.

Photoshop mockup example -->
[image: photoshop mockup example]

Is there a way to do this on a repeater element in CSS? We would like to use CSS so the elements are responsive.

**Here's what the element looks like together in their design:**
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is not going to be a visible difference on a 2px wide object with rounded corners versus a 2px wide object without on the web. You could show your design team the 2 side by side and I bet they'd have trouble distinguishing.

Comment: from a 3px wide object, you could use 1 pixel to round it somehow, but two will be slanted on one side. my screens do not split pixels as far i can see ;) try a background from an svg shrinked to 2 pixel width via background-size.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Use elements to work as borders, in grid layout. Flex would be better in 1D, but it didn't came to mind at first.

```css
.container{
   height:100px;
   width:95%;
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 3px 1fr 3px 1fr;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   background-color: #722020;
   color:#E3C5B8;
   font-family: cursive;
   font-size:20px;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   margin:30px auto;
}

.container>div{
  text-align:center;
}
.border{
  height:70%;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Crispiest <br>crust</div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div>Certified<br> Safe</div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div>Extreme <br>Durability</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)
2. Fill background `black`, 2px wide.
3. Make border round.
4. Place it on right.